# How to implement multiple GetHashCode methods?

Tags: c#, hashcode

I have an interface which defines a composite key:

```
public interface IKey : IEquatable<IKey>
{
    public bool KeyPart1 { get; }
    public uint KeyPart2 { get; }
    int GetHashCode(); // never gets called
}
```

I have an object (with an ID) to which I want to add the composite key interface:

```
public class MyObject: IEquatable<MyObject>, IKey
{
    public MyObject(int i, (bool keyPart1, uint keyPart2) key) {
    {
        Id=i;
        KeyPart1 = key.keyPart1;
        KeyPart2 = key.keyPart2;
    }
    
    public int Id { get; }
    public bool KeyPart1 { get; }
    public uint KeyPart2 { get; }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other) => this.Id == other.Id;

    public override bool Equals(object other) => other is MyObject o && Equals(o);
    public override int GetHashCode() => Id.GetHashCode();

    bool IEquatable<IKey>.Equals(IKey other) => this.KeyPart1 == other.KeyPart1
                                                && this.KeyPart2 == other.KeyPart2;
    int IKey.GetHashCode() => (KeyPart1, KeyPart2).GetHashCode(); // never gets called
}
```

However, when have a list of these objects and try to group them using the interface, the grouping fails:

```
var one = new MyObject(1, (true, 1));
var two = new MyObject(2, (true, 1));
var three = new MyObject(1, (false, 0));
var items = new[] { one, two, three };

var byId = items.GroupBy(i => i);
// result: { [one, three] }, { [two] } -- as expected

var byKey = items.GroupBy<MyObject, IKey>(i => i as IKey);

// result: { [one, two, three] } // not grouped (by 'id' or 'key')
// expected: { [one, two] }, { [three] }
```

I'd expected that `byId` would have the items grouped by the `Id` property, and `byKey` would have the items grouped by the `Key` property.

However, `byKey` is not grouped at all. It appears that the override `GetHashCode()` method is always used rather than the explicitly implemented interface method.

Is it possible to implement something like this, where the *type* of the item being grouped determines the hash method to use (avoiding an `EqualityComparer`)?

I noticed this problem when passing the cast objects to another method expecting an `IEnumerable<IKey>`. I have a few different types implementing `IKey` and those with an existing `GetHashCode()` method did not work, while the others did.

Please note the objects have been simplified here and that I cannot easily change the interfaces (e.g. to use `ValueTuple` instead).

Comment: Why do you want to avoid EqualityComparer? I would argue that is the way to go whenever you want more than one way to compare objects.

Comment: Unrelated tip: `Equals` should anticipate `null`, i.e. `=> other is not null && this.KeyPart1 == other.KeyPart1 && this.KeyPart2 == other.KeyPart2;`; you can also use a sneaky short-circuit in the `object` version: `public override bool Equals(object other) => other is MyObject typed && Equals(typed);`

Comment: @JonasH Only because it's 'unexpected'; I actually pass the objects (cast to `IKey`) to another method which takes `IKey`s (from a different implementation) and which normally works fine without an `EqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetHashCode()` used in equality is either:

- the one defined via `object.GetHashCode()`, if no equality comparer is provided
- `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode(T)`, if an equality comparer is provided

Adding your own `GetHashCode()` method on your own interface does nothing, and it will never be used, as it is not part of an API that the framework/library code knows about.

So, I'd forget about `IKey.GetHashCode()`, and either (or both):

- make `MyObject.GetHashCode()` provide the functionality you need, or
- provide a custom equality comparer *separately* to the `MyObject` instance

There are overloads of `GroupBy` that accept an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`, for the second option.